# calling a function inside a function in python with lists

Tags: python

was beginning my code, what I am trying to do is generate a list for some lottery mini-game im working on. It takes 10 numbers and 5 letters, I run a function to do that and it works just fine. Then I want to set the winning condition so I make another function and use the function within that function to fill the list with numbers/letters randomly. However, it always gives me the error "cannot choose from empty sequence" when I try to fill the list inside the win condition function. Here is my code so far

```
import string
def fill_list(random_list):
    random_list=[]
    for i in range(0,10):
        n=random.randint(1,10)
        random_list.append(n)
    for j in range(0,5):
        n=random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        random_list.append(n)
    return random_list

def win_condition(the_list):
    the_list=[]
    fill_list(the_list)
    win_list=[]
    for i in range(0,4):
        n=random.choice(the_list)
        win_list.append(n)
    return win_list

#Error code 
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Comment: your `fill_list(the_list)` returns `random_list` which needs to be store. `the_list = fill_list(the_list)`. without it, your `the_list` will remain empty, hence empty sequence.

Comment: Passing a list to `fill_list()` only makes sense if you do something with the passed list. But -- the very first line of that function definition has you throwing the passed list away in favor of a new empty list. You fill that new empty list, return it, and then promptly ignore the returned value in the calling code. You are being inconsistent. Either modify the passed list and return nothing, or pass no list at all (change the definition so that it takes no input) and assign the return value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

here is the problem in your code (in comment after lines):

```
def win_condition(the_list):
    the_list=[] #the_list let an empty list
    fill_list(the_list) #you invitate the fill_list() without data, and you get a list, that you dont use
    win_list=[]
    for i in range(0,4):
        n=random.choice(the_list) #the_list is yet empty, the program can not do something with an empty list
        win_list.append(n)
    return win_list
```

Try it:

```
import string
def fill_list():
    random_list=[]
    for i in range(0,10):
        n=random.randint(1,10)
        random_list.append(n)
    for j in range(0,5):
        n=random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        random_list.append(n)
    return random_list

def win_condition():
    the_list=fill_list()
    win_list=[]
    for i in range(0,4):
        n=random.choice(the_list)
        win_list.append(n)
    return win_list
```

I hope, it will be useful
Nohab

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are re-initializing the list after taking it as an argument. Also in `win_condition()` the output of `fill_list(the_list)` is now stored in `win_list` instead of initializing an empty list.

I tried to add minimum lines and just commented out the lines in your code that lead to the error.

```
import string
import random
def fill_list(random_list):
    # random_list=[]
    for i in range(0,10):
        n=random.randint(1,10)
        random_list.append(n)
    for j in range(0,5):
        n=random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        random_list.append(n)
    return random_list

def win_condition(the_list):
    # the_list=[]
    win_list = fill_list(the_list)
    # win_list=[]
    for i in range(0,4):
        n=random.choice(the_list)
        win_list.append(n)
    return win_list
print(win_condition([1,2, 3]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 7, 4, 2, 2, 2, 5, 10, 'e', 'A', 'N', 'S', 'x', 2, 2, 'A', 2]
```